# Как обратиться к метке по id?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, coffeescript

Создаю метки примерно таким образом

```
addressPointsCollection = new ymaps.GeoObjectCollection()
    addedAddressesCount = 0

    for address in addresses
      geoObject = new ymaps.GeoObject
        geometry:
          type: 'Point'
          coordinates: [address.latitude, address.longitude]
        properties:
          # iconContent: address.service.name
          hintContent: address.location
          id: address.id
      , preset: 'islands#darkGreenCircleDotIcon'


      addressPointsCollection.add geoObject
      addedAddressesCount += 1

      searchMap.geoObjects.add addressPointsCollection
      searchMap.setBounds(addressPointsCollection.getBounds(), { checkZoomRange: true });
```

Можно ли теперь зная id (id: address.id) обратиться к метке, к примеру чтобы изменить иконку?

Вообще хочу следующее: пользователь кликает-наводит курсор на элемент списка, в котором есть параметр с id, по этому id ищется метка и у нее что-либо меняетя, к примеру цвет иконки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То, что вы задали `id: address.id` в `properties` эффекта не даст.

Рекомендую хранить словарь `id: geoObject` в отдельном объекте, доступном в области видимости обработчика клика и выбирать нужный объект по `id` из этого словаря. Поскольку все ссылки на созданный объект (`geoObject`) равнозначны, действия с ними будут иметь одинаковый результат. То есть вы сможете изменять цвет и другие параметры например так

```
addressDict[id].options.set('preset', 'islands#darkRedCircleDotIcon');
```

Где `addressDict` - вышеупомянутый словарь